# How to get specific setting by settings_fields()?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options, settings-api

I am working on a plugin and on the settings page I have 2 settings
and I want to show Only one setting "backgroundColor" so how should i do that?

This is the code:

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">
<?php
    settings_errors();

    settings_fields( 'bg_color' );  **<<< I want only background settings to show how i can do it correclty?**

    do_settings_sections( 'plugin-style' );

    submit_button( __('Save settings', 'trans') );
                                        ?>
</form>


        /* Add Settings Field for Background Color */
    add_settings_field(
        'background-color',
        __('Background Color', 'trans'),
        'plugin_background_color_ca',
        'plugin-style',
        'style-settings-section-2',
        array(
            'name'      => 'bg_color',
            'id'        => 'style-settings-background-color',
            'class'     => 'style-settings-background-color',
            'options'   => $style_opts,
        )
    );

    /* Add Settings Field for Font Size */
    add_settings_field(
        'st-search-font-size',
        __('Font Size', 'trans'),
        'plugin_font_size_ca',
        'plugin-style',
        'style-settings-section-2',
        array(
            'name'      => 'font_size',
            'id'        => 'style-settings-font-size',
            'class'     => 'style-settings-font-size',
            'options'   => $style_opts,
        )
    );
```

N

Comment: `settings_fields` is just for the nonces and hidden inputs, it doesn't display the settings on the page. What's the problem that requires you to only show this? Are you trying to implement tabs or accordions? I'm not sure why you would register a section, put 2 settings in it, but only show 1

Comment: @TomJNowell yes i'm trying to show only one, not all settings, i can do it with javascript but i'm askin if there  away to do it with php.

Comment: can you explain why though? The context is important and might impact the solution significantly, you shouldn't need to do this but without knowing why you want it it's very difficult to say what you need to do ( or it may be a perfectly reasonable reason, in which case humour me anyway )